# Running uwsgi with mongoengine

Tags: flask, uwsgi, mongoengine

When I start uwsgi in multiprocess mode it says that pymongo should be run with connect=False. How can I setup connect=False if I run flask-mongoengine?

Answer (score 4):

Well, as Ju-won lee says, adding the option lazy solves the problem but it is highly discouraged as noted in the uwsgi documentation:

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ThingsToKnow.html

> uWSGI tries to (ab)use the Copy On Write semantics of the fork() call whenever possible. By default it will fork after having loaded your applications to share as much of their memory as possible. If this behavior is undesirable for some reason, use the lazy-apps option. This will instruct uWSGI to load the applications after each worker’s fork(). Beware as there is an older options named lazy that is way more invasive and highly discouraged (it is still here only for backward compatibility)

So, in case you want to use this option better use --lazy-apps. As I understand, the problem is that by default, mongoengine for flask initializes only one connection that forked proceses are not able to use (due to some restrictions in pymongo client). What makes the option of lazy apps is to load everything for each fork (which uses more memory).

There is a decorator that enables you to run code just after the prefork is made.

Just add to your application:

```
from flask.ext.mongoengine import MongoEngine
from uwsgidecorators import postfork

app = Flask(__name__)
# do whatever you want with the application

db = MongoEngine() # set db as MongoEngine (without any app or configuration)

@prefork
def setup_db():
    db.init_app(app) # this code actually calls to "connect" in pymongo

# define the rest of calls, etc
```

I hope this answer adds some clarification!

Comment: Should the decorator on setup_db() in your example code be @postfork rather than @prefork?

Comment: so this will fix problem ? warn MongoClient opened before fork. Create MongoClient only  ?

Answer (score 0):

use lazy option (--lazy) in your uwsgi.
mongoengine with multiprocessing occurs deadlock.. :(

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/MongoEngine/flask-mongoengine/blob/master/docs/index.rst

you can use set connect=False as below

```
app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {
    'host': 'mongodb://localhost/database_name',
    'connect': False,
}
# or
app.config['MONGODB_CONNECT'] = False
```